# RPM to invoke browser post installation

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, centos6.5

I am creating an RPM installer for centos 6.5, After installation i want the RPM to invoke the browser and show the installation report.

This installation report shows the details of how the installation went. Including errors and warnings that occurred while installation, goal is to clearly explain the user how the installation went.

I can easily double-click on the .rpm file and see the installation happening through the centos GNOME. But i don't see the successful installation message on the screen after the installation is done.

Can RPM invoke the browser post its installation ? Does rpm have the control of doing the same when the installation is happening through GUI - GNOME.
I have tried several blogs related to linux, rpm but haven't got lucky yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You may not have a browser installed.

You may not have X installed at all (unless your software requires it).

The user may be using ssh and not at a display.

Etc.

You cannot expect this to reliably work.

You can output to standard output which non-automatic processes will allow the user to see (if you can't when you double-click then that is because the handler is a terminal and it is exiting immediately when finished but you can change that, or install it via command manually).

You can also write an installation report output file that documentation instructs customers to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Etan, Yes! i can probably think of documenting the installation report. But i don't want the user to manually go and see the report instead it would be so user friendly if i were to show the report automatically post the installation by invoking the browser or some thing else.

Comment: And even if there is an X display handy and a browser installed, the user performing the actual package install (`root`) may not even have *access* to the display.

Comment: True, but if the user has access to the display can this be possible ?

Comment: You can attempt to do this, yes (using `xdg-open` or similar wrapper scripts/binaries). But it won't be at all reliable nor will it be expected. This isn't what rpms normally do. I know Windows installers frequently do this sort of thing (and I utterly despise it) but it isn't the sort of thing linux packages do.